Can Verilog functions access variables declared outside the function block?
There is a reg variable containing huge data array. This variable is declared and initialized inside a module.
I created a function inside the Verilog module to access this external data. Surprisingly, I am able to do so without any trouble.
So, is there any reason I should pass the values as input to the function when it can just access the external variables?
Here is a code example to show what I mean
module TestModule (
input clock,
output Out
);

    // Variable declared outside the function
    reg [7:0] externalVariable [10:0];

    // Function declaration
    function [7:0] myFunction;
        input arg;
    begin
        myFunction = externalVariable[arg];
    end
    endfunction

    always @(posedge clock) begin
        // Assign a value to the external variable
        Out <= myFunction(1);
    end

endmodule

I simulated the above example and it works. But why?

If you're talking about Verilog, the scope rules are defined in 1364-2005 12.7. SystemVerilog may have made some minor changes, but probably not, since that would break stuff. The rules state that

If an identifier is referenced directly (without a hierarchical path)
within a task, function, named block, or generate block, it shall be
declared either within the task, function, named block, or generate
block locally or within a module, task, function, named block, or
generate block that is higher in the same branch of the name tree that
contains the task, function, named block, or generate block.

So, within the function, you can directly reference something declared in the enclosing module.
Should you do this? Up to you. If you have any programming background, you would probably rather die first. Functions are meant to encapsulate functionality; pulling in arbitrary stuff from outside breaks this. It also makes the function 'impure', which isn't a concept in Verilog, but is probably the reason that you can't do fancy compile-time stuff in Verilog (things like pre-calculating filter coefficients, for example, which is common in Other HDLs, and has been for decades). SystemVerilog has added a concept of pure functions, so maybe they fixed that.
Interestingly, if you use a hierarchical identifier, you can access anything you want, anywhere. Again, whether this is good or bad is up to you, but don't do it in synthesisable code. It can be fantastically useful in testbenches, and I make extensive use of it in code which is compiled down to produce Verilog. Interestingly, the inability to use hierarchical identifiers like this in An Other HDL was always a major flaw, and took years to fix.

A function or task can certainly reference signals declared outside of it. But one thing you need to be careful of is sensitivity with combinational logic. If instead you tried to use a continuous assignment like
assign someWire = myFunction(someIn);

or
always @(*) someReg = myFunction(someIn);

Then simulation only calls myFunction when someIn changes its value, not when externalVariable changes.
SystemVerilog addresses this problem with the alway_comb block. It in-lines all function calls and makes the always process sensitive to all external variable changes.


Can Verilog functions access variables declared outside the function block?

Short Answer: Yes
Why?:
Each module creates scope; variable externalVariable is in the TestModule module scope.
Therefore externalVariable is available to Verilog constructs in the same scope.
I would consider adding argument(s) and variables as needed to localize the behavior and declare the function storage as automatic.  The default storage for functions is static (shared variables).
Declaring the automatic function makes the it reentrant, causes dynamic allocation of storage for each time its called, rather than sharing variables between different invocations of the task.
Declaring the function automatic looks like this
function automatic [7:0] myFunction;

See IEEE 1364-2005 (last Verilog specification) section 10 Tasks and functions for more.
You may find this post helpful re Verilog Variables Module Scope

I don't know what simulator you are using but your code did not compile for me when I used the commercial simulators on www.edaplayground.com
I get the error
design.sv, 20
  Net type cannot be used on the left side of this assignment.
  The offending expression is : Out
  Source info: Out <= myFunction(1);

Which is saying part Out must change from:
output Out

to
output reg Out   

The default for outputs is type wire, and wires can't be driven from an always block in Verilog.
You can also change the file extensions to .sv, thus invoking the SystemVerilog compiler.  In SystemVerilog use type logic to replace wire/reg and the tool will do the right thing and free you from the wire/reg rules.

That was just an example code I quickly wrote to show what the question means. I am not allowed to share the actual code. So are you saying, that the only problem following the above design (apart from the blocking operator) is that the user won't know how the function works. Am I right?

@Dave59 and others have pointed out potential down sides of accessing a variable defined outside the fn.  I recommend that you understand and retain their points then use your judgment accordingly. There are lint tools you can run on Verilog designs which will flag things like this with different severity. Opinions vary on the value of lint tools . A blocking assignment in a function models combinational logic (a mux in this case) You have a bus mux driving a single bit flip-flop
